# how to control views of gridview special items dynamically

Tags: android, gridview, customization

i want to control(remove(make gone) , add(make visible), set data) views in gridview items ,for example when user taps to download button in a gridview item , the grid item's progressBar runs its progress ,after finishing download ; the dowload button gets gone and open button gets visible and maybe more actions like changing background for delete button , matching my codes after taping to download button my orders runs properly but when user scroling gridview some items gets similar effects that i order to last grid item [visibleing open button and etc] and i see some same items in grid , can any body help me to solve this ? or offering to use recyclerview instead?

this is my adapter class

```
public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{
private Context mContext;
private final String[] web;
private final int[] Imageid;

public CustomGrid(Context c,String[] web,int[] Imageid ) {
        mContext = c;
        this.Imageid = Imageid;
        this.web = web;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
        return web.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View grid;
        if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single,parent,false);
        } else {
                grid = convertView;
        }
        final ProgressBar downloadPb =(ProgressBar)grid.findViewById(R.id.single_gride_progressBar);
        final Button downloadBtn = (Button) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_single_download_btn);
        final Button openBtn = (Button) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_single_open_btn);
        final Button deleteBtn = (Button) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_single_delete_btn);

        downloadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        new CountDownTimer(5000,1){ //simulating download progress
                                @Override
                                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                        if(millisUntilFinished<=500){
                                                downloadPb.setProgress(100);
                                        }else if(millisUntilFinished<=1000){
                                                downloadPb.setProgress(80);
                                        }else if(millisUntilFinished<=2000){
                                                downloadPb.setProgress(60);
                                        }else if(millisUntilFinished<=3000){
                                                downloadPb.setProgress(40);
                                        }else if(millisUntilFinished<=4000){
                                                downloadPb.setProgress(20);
                                        }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFinish(){
                                        downloadBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        openBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        deleteBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.delete_selector);
                                }
                        }.start();
                }
        });
        TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
        textView.setText(web[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);

        return grid;
}
}
```

this is my activity

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {

String[] mArrayNames =     {"english","italic","germany","french","russina","persian","indian","arabic","spanish","latin",};
int[] mArrayPics = { R.drawable.c118_1 , R.drawable.c104 , R.drawable.c115_2 , R.drawable.c117 , R.drawable.c613_8 , R.drawable.c103 , R.drawable.c103_1 , R.drawable.c114_1 , R.drawable.c613_7 , R.drawable.r155};
GridView grid ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(Main2Activity.this, mArrayNames, mArrayPics);
grid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView45);
grid.setAdapter(adapter);
grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,int position, long id) {
    }
});
}
}
```

Comment: You have an understanding of syntax in programming languages - why not so in English?

Comment: i just have to say sorry for my bad english